# R recalculate data to weekly usage

Tags: r, date, dataframe, google-analytics, transformation

I have the following problem to solve: I download the data from Google Analytics, consisting of three columns: column A the factor variable (user ID), column B, the date of the session, and column C number of sessions or other metrics.

I want to create a table, where in the first column I have the factor, and subsequent columns depict weeks 1-8. R is to calculate the number of sessions for each element (factor) depending on the first session date for each week, as different users have started using the web-page on different dates. This should show how engaged users were during the project of 8 weeks.

Here is the example:

```html
df <- data.frame(
        fac=c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d"), 
        date=c("2017-01-01","2017-01-05","2017-01-13","2017-01-25","2017-02-10","2017-01-06","2017-01-16","2017-01-28","2017-02-02","2017-02-07","2017-01-11","2017-01-19","2017-01-24","2017-01-31","2017-02-09","2017-01-12","2017-01-24","2017-01-29","2017-02-04","2017-02-19","2017-03-08"), 
        sessions=c(1,2,3,6,5,1,3,2,3,3,1,5,3,2,4,1,3,5,2,6,6)
        )
```

Should look something like this:
[end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpR7R.png)

example:

Any R package ca be used, but I would rather like to avoid loops, if possible.

Comment: Important to note: weeks do not represent calendar weeks, but rather, the first event date determines the first day of the first week in 8 week experiment, whatever the date of start is. So the data frame consists of factors x 8 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `dcast` to convert the 'long' to 'wide' format.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'fac' and 'date' converted to `week`, get the first row of Subset of data.table (`.SD[1L]`) and then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[, .SD[1L], .(fac, Week = factor(paste0("Week", week(as.Date(date))), 
              levels = paste0("Week", 1:10)))], fac ~ Week, drop = FALSE)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, we can use similar methodology

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
      group_by(fac, Week = factor(paste0("Week", 
               week(as.Date(date))), levels = paste0("Week", 1:10))) %>% 
      slice(1) %>% 
      select(-date) %>% 
      spread(Week, sessions)
```

Comment: Thanks your your proposed solution, though I think I haven't expressed myself very clear: the weeks are not supposed to reflect real calendar weeks, but the weeks of participation in an experiment, in which the website was used for. So any date, when any person (factor) uses the website for the first time (first entry for the factor) should be the first day of his/her first week. So the whole data frame should be factors x 8 weeks. Could you give me a hint how to transform your previous solutions to achieve this? Thanks a lot!